# unresolved JQuery Dialog: Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dialog (users.html) from which to load a second dialog (user.html); when I close the second dialog I get the error.
qualcuso can help me?
thank you!

I below shows the code of the two files that I simplified:

file users.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <title>Users...</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>   
        <div id="div_users" title="Users...">
            <button id="btn_user">User</button>
        </div> 
        <div id="div_users_user" >
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div_users').dialog({
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        close: function(event, ui){
            console.log('close Users');
            $('#div_users').dialog('destroy').remove();
        },

        buttons: {
            "Close": function(event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_user").click(function () {
            console.log("New");
            $('#div_users_user').load('user.html');
        });
    });

</script>
</html>
```

file user html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <title>User...</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_add_edit_user" title="New User...">
        <div id="div_user_main">
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog({
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        close: function(event, ui){
            $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog('destroy').remove();
        },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function() {
                //TO DO..
                $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog('close');

            },
            "Cancel": function(event, ui) {
                $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second file ("user.html") actually not a full page but is more of a snippet. Thus it does not need to declare again jquery and jqueryui. It turns out that you declare them twice and there is conflict.

Comment: no .. this is not the reason; if you try you'll see it.

Comment: Well, to be precise in the above code, you have a whole lot of mistakes. Tags "meta" and "link" must be closed. Button initialization dialogue should be as specified here: http:// api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons. And so on. I have corrected these errors and remove references to jquery and jqueryui in user.html file.

Comment: ok .. I did corrected the code by following your suggestions and this now works.
could you please correct also the last few changes?

Comment: see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

users.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <title>Users...</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>   
        <div id="div_users" title="Users...">
            <button id="btn_user">User</button>
        </div> 
        <div id="div_users_user" >
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div_users').dialog({
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        close: function(event, ui){
            console.log('close Users');
            $('#div_users').dialog('destroy').remove();
        },

        buttons: {
            "Close": function(event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_user").click(function () {
            console.log("New");
            $('#div_users_user').load('user.html');
        });
    });

</script>
</html>
```

user.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


    <title>User...</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_add_edit_user" title="New User...">
        <div id="div_user_main">
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog({
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        close: function(event, ui){
            console.log('close');
            //$('#div_add_edit_user').parent.dialog('destroy').remove();
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function() {
                //TO DO..
                $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog('close');

            },
            "Cancel": function(event, ui) {
                console.log('cancel');
                //$('this').dialog('close');
                $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post code which I did. Tested in Mozilla Firefox 49. Works like this: when the page is fully loaded once the first dialogue opens; if you click on the "user" opens another dialogue. This second dialog is closed correctly after clicking either the "Save" button or "Cancel". No errors in develover tools no. If I understand correctly this is exactly what was required.

users.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>Users...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="div_users" title="Users...">
            <button id="btn_user">User</button>
        </div>
        <div id="div_users_user">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div_users').dialog({
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                modal: true,
                resizable: true,
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Close",
                    click: function () {
                        $('#div_users').dialog("close");
                    }
                }]
            });
            $("#btn_user").click(function () {
                console.log("New");
                $('#div_users_user').load('user.html');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

user.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_add_edit_user" title="New User...">
        <div id="div_user_main">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#div_add_edit_user').dialog({
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                modal: true,
                buttons: [
                   {
                       text: "Save",
                       click: function () {
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       text: "Cancel",
                       click: function () {
                           $("#div_add_edit_user").dialog("close");
                       }
                   }
                ]
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```